# React: Calling methods inside a variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to run a simple React component and not sure why this isn't working.

For some reason, `addRows` isn't running. Can someone explain why?

```
var CreateRows = React.createClass({
    addRows : function(){
        return (
                <tr>
                    <td>Morgan</td>
                    <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>

            )
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <tbody>
                {this.addRows}
            </tbody>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Invoke the method - {this.addRows()}

Comment: thank you. I've been following this tutorial - https://tylermcginnis.com/react-js-tutorial-pt-1-a-comprehensive-guide-to-building-apps-with-react-js-8ce321b125ba#.5w3ath7hc They don't use () to invoke functions in it, but yet it works. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function with `{ this.addRows() }`. With your code you are only referring to the function but not invoking it. Such a statement could be used for defining a function e.g. like `onClick={ this.addRows }`

Comment: ahh, that explains why question to the comment! thank you.

Comment: Great :) Please accept my answer as correct in that case ;)